# How to push a view controller in Landscape mode in navigation controller while other are in Portrait in iPhone ios 8

Tags: ios8, orientation

If I present that controller using below code then its working fine & it is in Landscaspe mode but instead of presenting that controller if I push it then it apperas in Portrait mode.

```
 AppDelegate *app= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

app.islandscape=YES;//For Landscape Mode

iPhoneSignatureScreenViewController *r=[[iPhoneSignatureScreenViewController alloc]init];
[self presentViewController:r animated:YES completion:nil];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

I have used Custom navigation controllers subclass & bool variable to maintain which controller should be in Portrait & which in Landscape.For other controller islandscape is set to NO.

In my custom Navigation Controller class I have implemented :-

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
 return YES;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
AppDelegate *appdelgate= (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

if (appdelgate.islandscape) {

    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;

}
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had much luck doing something like this in a navigation controller push. The `+
attemptRotationToDeviceOrientation` method sounds like it should help but hasn't for me. The only way to reliably present a view in a different orientation than the current top view is a modal presentation.